# Excel VBA how vlookup or an alternative way of getting the dyanmic value

Tags: vba, excel, copy, vlookup

I spend the last month making a program that finds specified strings, copies the data underneath it, and builds a Rawdata table from it. Problem is, all it does is copies and pastes, so if the value were to change, the value in the Rawdata table would not. I'm familiar with the =vlookup function but I don't know how to use it in VBA, and I'm not even sure if that's the right function to use in this instance.

Here is the code for looking up a string and copying the data underneath it.

```
    SearchString = "#Regimen"
    Application.FindFormat.Clear
' loop through all sheets
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
' Find first instance on sheet
        Set cl = sh.Cells.Find(What:=SearchString, _
            After:=sh.Cells(1, 1), _
            LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not cl Is Nothing Then
' If found, remember location
            FirstFound = cl.Address
' Dim RangeToCopy As Range, DestRow As Long
                    Set RangeToCopy = Range(cl.Offset(1, 0), cl.Offset(numRowsForProducts, 0))
                    RangeToCopy.Copy
                    DestRow = Sheets("Template").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    Sheets("Template").Range("B" & 3 + iCounter).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next
```

Tl:DR, I want copy a dynamic range from one Sheet and put it into another, so that when the original changes, it also changes in the other sheet.

Comment: You know the address of cl, so instead of copying the values, you could just make the formula of the target cell be equal to the address of the offset values. Do this by either looping through the columns in your DestRow, or by using the FormulaR1C1 function, which defines a formula based on the destination cell's position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where you want the destination row to start. You set destination row, but then use iCounter. I used iCounter as you did. Please let me know if you want it to paste at the bottom of the sheet.

```
    SearchString = "#Regimen"
    Application.FindFormat.Clear
' loop through all sheets
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
' Find first instance on sheet
        Set cl = sh.Cells.Find(What:=SearchString, _
            After:=sh.Cells(1, 1), _
            LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not cl Is Nothing Then
' If found, remember location
            for i = 0 to numRowsForProducts - 1
                Sheets("Template").Range("B" &  3 + iCounter + i).formula = "=" & sh.name & "!" & cl.offset(i,0).address
            next
        End If
    Next
```